# Dynamically load (page3.php) into a div in (page1.php) by a link inside (page2.php) which is previously loaded inside the same div

Tags: php, javascript, function, dynamic, document-ready

I'm able to dynamically call page2.php inside a div in page1.php without page reload by 2 js functions written in the header section of page1.php, but the issue is that after I call page2.php I want to click a link inside it to load page3.php in the same DIV of page1.php instead of page2.php, when I click it I get only (page3.php) in the browser

page1.php:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>`
function updateContainer( url ) {`
    dynamicCon = '#dynamicContainer';    
    ObjTag = $( dynamicCon );
    ObjTag.load( url );
}
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( 'a[data-fancybox-group="dynamicLoad"]' ).bind( "click", function( event ) {
    url = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
    updateContainer( url );
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dynamicContainer"></div>
<a href="blabla" onclick="this.href='page2.php'" data-fancybox-group="dynamicLoad">Load Page 2</a>
</body>
```

page2.php:

```
<a href="blabla" onclick="this.href='page3.php'" data-fancybox-group="dynamicLoad">Load Page 3</a>
```

Comment: This question is lacking a question.

Comment: This makes my eyes hurt.

Comment: That's a long sentence! There should be a badge for that.

Comment: That just about [monsters the elipses](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16967829/1)

Comment: sorry, it's a question for smarties and php/js gurus only!