# Css Align Textbox from top

Tags: css, html, css-float

on my website i have a text box that is in the center of the web page but the problem is I need it to be to be 25px from the top of the web page . i have try d **top:25px;** but it still dosnt work.. i was going to upload my code to a **Jsfiddle** but the text box wouldn’t work correctly so ill just post a link to my drop box and include the css below

**Dropbox**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5lw3r9impok4eo8/MyWebsite.zip

**Css**

```
/** Advanced Css Search Box */

#advsearch {
margin: auto;              **Puts Textbox In The Center**
}
#advsearch input[type="text"] {
background: url(images/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
color: #bebebe;
width: 150px;
 padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}

#advsearch input[type="text"]:focus {
width: 200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="advanced search">
   <form method="get" action="/search" id="advsearch">
    <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can't you use margin-top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id="advanced_search">
   <form method="get" action="/search" id="advsearch">
    <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
  </form>
</div>

#advanced_search {margin-top: 25px;}
```

OR

`#advsearch {margin: 25px auto;}`

Comment: @AndréMazoni and the OP (Original Poster) i have just payed for a website im working on it solo could use some help . if you all want u should email me tonnajacob@gmail.com ill send u the link to my forum to register

Comment: @AndréMazoni  http://jsfiddle.net/K6fey/1/ is my update with my code (most of it) if u hover over Products the dropdown wont show up . if u remove the search code it works correctly..

Answer (score 2):

A couple things:

The `id` you've specified...

```
<div id="advanced search">
```

and the CSS selector you're using...

```
#advsearch
```

don't match up.

You could fix by specifying the following in your HTML element:

```
<div id="advsearch">
```

Then, it's a matter of specifying the margin-top value for the input...

```
#advsearch input[type="text"] {
   margin-top: 25px;
   width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: actualy the **form** holds the advsearch id the div is for labeling because i have alot of html

Comment: if u hover over the word Products the menu dosent show up but if u move down a mit more it does.. if u remove the search code from the css and the html it works fine..

Comment: if u want a job send me an email tonnajacob@gmail.com i could use some help on my website . email me for more info

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 methods to do it by your css file:

`method a:`

```
position: absolute;
top: 25px;
```

`method b:`

```
display: inline;
float: top;
```

try the both to see what is the best for you according to the other styling around the element.

Comment: and what does that suppose to mean?? I use float all the time!

Comment: are you pro with Jquery? check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974756/jquery-ajax-function-return-mysqli-max-user-connection-warning
and this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970312/dynamically-load-page3-php-into-a-div-in-page1-php-by-a-link-inside-page2-p

Comment: i use float:top; and float center all the time aswell it does work